# JSON.parse doesnt working when receives Gson string... "Undefined" value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, gson

```
Collection lista_interpretes;
lista_interpretes = sistema.buscarInterpretes();
if (!lista_interpretes.isEmpty()) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String test = gson.toJson(lista_interpretes);

  try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) { 
     out.println(test); //USING GSON DOESNT WORKING... [{"cod":"4","name":"Paul"}]
     out.println("{\"cod\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Paul\"}"); /*THIS TEST DOENST USING GSON WORKS. WHATS GOING ON? THE DIFFERENCE IS []*/
  }
}
```

In Javascript Im using var X = JSON.parse(req.responseText), but I get "undefined" value from X.name. I tried

Comment: What is `lista_interpretes`? What you have in responce? I suppose you have string like `{"correct":"json"}"cod":"4","name":"Paul"}`. You can't concatenate data such way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have array of entities in responce. Because `lista_interpretes` is Collection.

But in javascript code you want to get single entity.

Try this:

```
X = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
X = X[0];
console.log(x.name);
```